# Visual studio code isn't show tips about library's properties and methods

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw that VS can help you with some objects properties or methods when you only write dot after object name VS will show you their properties and methods, but when I try to get help with PIXI.js library, it isn't shown me that. Can it be configurable? Thanks.

[Myself created object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEME4.png)

[PIXI.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHWIx.png)

Comment: You [like Typescript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense), not Javascript.  Who doesn't.

Comment: VSCode has its own tag, so don't misuse others.